# Where are Notepad++ config files?

Tags: notepad++

I know this question has been asked before and I have read many answers from various forums regarding this issue but I have never ever been able to find my *actual* configuration files for Notepad++.

I have been using Notepad++ for many years and periodically something will happen or I will change computers and I will have to reinstall it and then reconfigure ever setting all over again since I have no prior config files that I can just copy back.  Very frustrating.

I have always set a "DoLocalConf.xml" in the install directory because it has been said that this will store settings in the install directory (but doesn't).  I have also looked in the folder: user / Roaming / appdata for notepad++ and the settings are *not* there either (even though the folder exists depending on if I have creatd DoLocalConf.xml or not).  -- To be more specific - the CONFIG files are there but they never change after I have setup my preferences and such.

I use Beyond Compare to diff them every time and they stay identical and the timestamp does not change. A very simple example is I go to preferences, set "show close button", "draw vertical line", Set backup directory, ... and then close Notepad++ and none of the notepad++ xml files get updated. I don't understand how this is possible.  Every once in a while I will spend hours reading forums and searching for these settings only to finally give up until the next time I have to reinstall.  There *must* be something else to check where they are stored.

I have a Windows 7 professional setup and (currently) using the latest Notepad++ 6.2.3

Comment: You may find the option to store settings in 'the cloud' interesting: Settings > Preferences > Cloud. I have Google Drive installed on most of my pc's, and it keeps all NP++ settings perfectly synced.

Answer (score 23):

The configuration files are typically stored in the user's roaming app data folder.  I have a standard Notepad++ setup (v6.1).  I made no modifications during installation.  My config files are stored in:

```
%appdata%\Notepad++
```

Which resolves to:

```
C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\Notepad++
```

I verified this by opening `%appdata%\Notepad++\config.xml` and checking the value for `<GUIConfig name="StatusBar">` tag, which was set to `show`.  I then went into Settings -> Preferences and unchecked the "Show status bar" checkbox.  I then closed Notepad++ and reopened the config.xml file.  The value now shows `hide` instead of `show`.

---

If you did check the "Don't use the %APPDATA% folder" option at install time, Notepad++ may be trying to write configuration files to your install directory  but failing, or the Windows compatibility layer may be giving you a [virtualized](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb756960.aspx) version of the install directory to write to.  In that case I would uninstall, and reinstall using standard settings.

Comment: Is there nowhere within the program to tell you where the config files are kept?

Comment: @bgmCoder – Notepad++ will tell you config path indirectly via **Settings** > **Edit Popup ContextMenu**. Mentioned config file opens in the editor and its directory is the directory which also contains all other config files.